# regex to remove words that contains special character along with url in R

Tags: regex, string, r, gsub

I want to remove words that contains special character except c#/c++. I also like to remove url present in a sentence.

For Eg my input is:

```
x <- "Google in the la#d of What c#  chell//oo grr+m my Website is: c++ http://www.url.com/bye"
```

what I am doing is

```
gsub("http://(\\S+)|\\s*[\\^w\\s]\\s*[^c#c++\\s]","",x)
```

My expected output is

```
"Google in the of What c#  my Website c++"
```

But I am getting

```
"Google in the la#d of What c#  chell//oo grr+m my Webte i c++ "
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a single regex that, while horribly ugly, does the job:

```
gsub('(?:^|(?<=\\s))(?:(c\\+\\+|c#)|http://[^\\s]*|[^\\s]*[#/:+]+[^\\s]*)(?:\\s|$)', '\\1', x, perl=TRUE)
## [1] "Google in the of What c# my Website c++"
```

This uses the expression `[#/:+]` as the match for "special characters" other than those present in `c#` and `c++`.

Breaking this down:

First, a space must be present (but not actually matched) or it must be the beginning of the text for the match to begin:  `(?:^|(?<=\\s))`.  The choice is presented as a non-capturing group with `(?:)`.  This is important as we want to capture `c#` and `c++` in the expression (later).

Next, a selection of three choices is given, with `|` as separators: `(?:(c\\+\\+|c#)|http://[^\\s]*|[^\\s]*[#/:+]+[^\\s]*)`.  This choice is another non-capturing group.

The first two selections (actually one choice, but two possibilities for the match in the regex) matches `c++` or `c#` and captures the value with `(c\\+\\+|c#)`.  Otherwise, a URL representation may be matched with `http://[^\\s]*` or a word with special character with `[^\\s]*[#/:+]+[^\\s]*`.  The URL or word with special character is not captured.

Finally, a space must be present or it must be the end of the string, as specified by (?:\s|$)the final non-capturing group: `(?:\\s|$)`

Then the whole expression is replaced by the first capture, which may be empty.  If it is nonempty, the capture will contain the string `c#` or `c++`.

You do need `perl=TRUE` for this expression to be valid.

Comment: Note that matching for the URL is redundant, if words with `/` are rejected.  I left that in because it was explicitly in the question, but the definition of "special character" was not.

Comment: now if I need to remove all the words that contains special char like $, %, & etc... like wha$t..

Comment: @tanay Add those characters to the regex character class `[#/:+]` in the expression `[^\\s]*[#/:+]+[^\\s]*`.  As it is, it matches those four characters only.  So you want: `[^\\s]*[#/:+$%&]+[^\\s]*`

Comment: But if there is a word like **in\\\n** then it is creating error if i put '\' in the class **[#/:+]**

Comment: @tanay Backslashes are evil everywhere, due to various levels of interpretation.  To match values with backslashes in R, put four of them in the character class!  For example, `[#/:+$%&\\\\]`

Answer (score 3):

How about this?  It seems to do the trick.  It seemed a bit easier to split up the string first with `strsplit`.  One example below uses `grep`, and the other `gsub`. They each use a different regular expression. Also, the arguments to `grep` can be **very** useful at times.

```
> newX <-unlist(strsplit(x, "\\s"))
```

With `grep`:

```
> newX2 <- grep("((^[a-z]{2,3}$)|[A-Z]{1})|(c#|(\\+{2}))", newX, value = TRUE)
> paste(newX2, collapse = " ")
[1] "Google in the of What c# my Website c++"
```

With `gsub`.  This is actually much easier...they key idea is to determine the pattern of where the punctuation shows up within the characters.

```
> paste(gsub("[a-z]{2,3}(:|#)|(\\+|//)[a-z{1}]", "", newX), collapse = " ")
[1] "Google in the of What c#  my Website c++"
```

Comment: This type of solution is easier to understand than a regular expression that does the whole job.

Comment: it is great...simple and elegant...I would loved to accept your answer but sorry I have already selected one...

Comment: I agree.  The arguments to `grep` are useful most times as well.

Comment: @tanay You can change your selection.  You should select the answer that best answers your question.

Comment: @tanay I'm not worried about it.  Do whatever you want. I really just love a good regex challenge.:)

Comment: @RichardScriven That's why I did it all in one go, for the challenge.  In "real life" I would have written something more like what you have.